# Correct way to sample

Tags: distributions, sampling, random-variable

I have two **independent** random variables with known distributions. I want to sample a point from the space formed by these two. Example, x1~N(0,1) and x2~N(0,1). This will create a space with circular contours (as they are independent). I want to sample a point(which will be a 2d vector) from there.

Assume X1 is the random variable corresponding to x1 and similarly X2. Should I sample X1 and X2 independently to obtain this 2d point or should I sample from the joint distribution of X1 and X2? Intuitively, I think that we should sample from the joint distribution, but I am not sure without a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case when your two variables are independent, simulating independently from the marginals is equivalent to simulating from the joint distribution.

A (very) rough proof that this is the case is writing the joint distribution $p(x_1, x_2)$ as $p(x_2|x_1)p(x_1)$. Since the two are independent, $p(x_2|x_1)=p(x_2)$ and one simulated value for $X_1$ is not imposing any conditions over the corresponding simulation of $X_2$.

Comment: Could you clarify on how sampling a 2d point from p(x1,x2)=p(x1)p(x2) is equivalent to sampling two 1d points from p(x1) and p(x2) separately? I mean, how is sampling from product of two distributions is same as sampling from each individually

Comment: You are sampling two independent 1d points $x_1$ and $x_2$ and defining the random vector $X = (X_1, X_2)$ as the concatenation of these 1d points. You are not sampling from the product of two distributions. The joint density is given by the product of marginal densities, that is the definition of independence.